# Dinamically load XAML in UserControl for Excel Add In (VB)

Tags: vb.net, xaml, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel Add In in which I intend to dinamically load a XAML canvas to a WPF UserControl.
The code below worked fine in a full WPF template...

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO
Class MainWindow

    Private Sub btnLoadXAML_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Try
            Dim FlDialog As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
            FlDialog.ShowDialog()

            Dim lFlName As String = FlDialog.FileName

            'load selected file
            Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(lFlName, FileMode.Open)

            Dim gridToLoad As New Canvas
            With gridToLoad
                .Height = 300
                .Width = 300
            End With

            gridToLoad = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(fs)
            grdLoadXAML.Children.Add(gridToLoad)

            fs.Close()


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

...but when I use it on a Excel Add In template, I can't refer to a XAML object via VB code, such as:

```
 Dim gridToLoad As New Canvas
```

I mean "New Canvas" doesn't seem to be "imported" into this kind of template. I couldn't find which library to refer to make this work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, 
Just a few minutes after I've tried to build the project and Visual Basic itself gave me the answer!
Just had to add reference for System.Xaml (dumb!).
Thanks anyway!! :)
Best.